# Does a running motor generate photons?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons

Since a motor consists of electric field generated through AC current and a fixed magnetic field (permanent magnets), does it generate photons?

Comment: Does it emit electromagnetic radiation? Probably, but the motor may be shielded to minimize that radiation. Is there any problem that is more easily solved by describing the radiation in terms of photons instead of using Maxwell's theory? For such long wavelengths, maybe not. IDK though. I am neither an electrical engineer nor a physicist.

Comment: Is there a way to determine what type of radiation is emitted?

Comment: Yes, by energy level of electron, If lower energy then radio and microwave, more energy then  infrared radiation, higher energy level then X-rays and gamma rays. So, whether a motor emits radio waves, visible light, or something else depends on how much energy the electrons gain during their movements.

Comment: Note that all of the "types" of radiation mentioned by DimensionDestroyer really are just different energy/frequency/wavelength bands of electromagnetic radiation. They are mostly distinguished by the different technologies that we use to generate and/or detect them. E.G., "visible" radiation is defined as that band of wavelengths to which our eyes respond. X-rays are that band that we can generate by bombarding a metal target with high energy electrons,  etc. But, they're _all_ just photons/electromagnetic waves.

Comment: I want to inform that i am also not a electrical engineer or physicist.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Noting that effects change with frequency for some situations. The most important for we biologicals being the boundary for 'ionising radiation' starting somewhere around 'very deep blue'.

Answer (score 14):

It does. There are at least three mechanisms.

First, if the moving parts of the motor have electric charge or magnetic dipole moments, those fields are reconfigured as the parts move. The information about that reconfiguration is carried by photons. The spectrum of these photons will be complicated, but the lowest-frequency component will have the same frequency as the period of the motor's rotation.

Second, if the motor contains intermittent electrical contacts, electromagnetic radiation will be emitted as those contacts are made and broken. This radiation can have high-frequency radio components, which you are most likely to detect as interference with a radio that you are trying to use for something else.

Finally, if the motor gets hot, it will emit infrared thermal photons. As a rule, if your motor gets hot enough to glow in the visible, you should turn it off.

Comment: Comment only: May b worth noting that frequencies below rotation period will occur due to multiple phases and/or pole pairs and/ot=r magnet:coil ratios. Also, second order effects can occur due to periodic structures in the motors construction.

Comment: Yes, it will be quite complicated.

Comment: While otherwise a good answer, this totally misses the net frequency photons emitted by any AC motor. For induction motors, this will be the main component of the emissions, for universal motors running on AC, emissions will be a mix of net frequency and rotation frequency based harmonics.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica Do you mean the radiation with the same frequency as the power line? I would argue that radiation is emitted by the power supply. If you mean something different, please clarify.

Comment: I mean the radiation emitted by the changing/rotating magnetic field within the motor. Of course, the power line does emit via its changing electric field, but there is typically not much space between the wires. The rotating/pulsing magnetic field, however, spans across the entire rotor.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica I could make sense of second part (arcing) and third part (eddy currents), can you explain the first mechanism in detail? or point me towards a guide for dummies that explains it please? :-)

Comment: @Yashodhar.Rao A rotating magnetic field is a changing magnetic field. And a changing magnetic field emits electromagnetic waves just like a changing electric field does. Or, in short, any changing field emits waves. Even if you just attached a bar magnet to a fast rotating axis, it would start emitting radio waves of the same frequency it is rotating at.

Comment: Hmm. "if the moving parts of the motor have electric charge or magnetic dipole moments"? How can you have a motor otherwise? The entire mechanism of an electric motor is based on massive emission/absorption of photons. In the near field we call this "induction"; in the far field we call it "radiation". But Maxwells equations only have E, B, and t, no other magic sauce. Photons are poor model for EM effects generally and induction especially.

Comment: @johnjbarton The sentence you quote was intended as a humorously obvious understatement. The rest of your remarks feel more like an additional answer to the question than it does like a suggestion for improving or clarifying this answer.

Comment: @rob I found your answer very puzzling: sensible except for the very first bit. So my suggestion is to try it without the humor, which I completely missed. I think that is why the internet invented emotions ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when an electric motor operates with **Alternating Current (AC)** and interacts with a fixed magnetic field from permanent magnets, it can indeed produce electromagnetic radiation in the form of **photons**. This happens because of the way electric charges, like electrons, move within the motor's coils.

But The main purpose of the motor is to convert **electrical** **energy** into **mechanical** **motion**, and the energy lost as radiation is usually quite insignificant compared to the motor's overall energy use.

Many Motor is shielded to reduce electromagnetic radiation for safety.

Comment: Is there a way to determine what type of radiation is emitted?

Comment: You can be sure it's (mostly) radio waves. As the other answer points, "the lowest-frequency component will have the same frequency as the period of the motor's rotation" and your motor", and no real motor is fast enough for that period reach the infrared.